# WebGL LookAt works on -z but broke on +z?

Tags: matrix, graphics, 3d, webgl

I'm trying to build my own camera class in WebGL for learning purposes. It's almost complete but I have 1 slight issue with the lookAt function. If I translate my object in the -z direction then it will work fine but once I move it in the +z direction it acts as if it's doing the opposite and the object will begin to stretch across the screen if I move the camera up or down.

This is what I currently have:

```
var zAxis = new Vector(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z)
    .subtract(target)
    .normalize();

var xCross = math.cross(up.flatten(3), zAxis.flatten(3));
var xAxis = new Vector(xCross[0], xCross[1], xCross[2]).normalize();

var yCross = math.cross(zAxis.flatten(3), xAxis.flatten(3));
var yAxis = new Vector(yCross[0], yCross[1], yCross[2]).normalize();

var orientation = [
    xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z, 0,
    yAxis.x, yAxis.y, yAxis.z, 0,
    zAxis.x, zAxis.y, zAxis.z, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
];

var translation = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z, 1
];

this.multiply(translation);
this.multiply(orientation);
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: I think you need to post more code. How are you using that matrix? What's your shader look like. I'd think you'd need the inverse of that matrix in your shader

Comment: You should compare your `lookAt` implementation with say, the glMatrix implementation and see if they returns identical results.